# Parallelization using multiprocessing running processes sequentially instead of simultaneously

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to parallelize a piece of code given below using the multiprocessing module. Everything I try leads to each child process being run one after the other even though they all have different PIDs. I have tried:

1. CentOS and MacOS
2. Context as spawn and as fork
3. Using Queues and using pools
4. Using Apply and Using map and their async versions
5. Adding/removing pool.join() and Process.join()

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

fs.py:

```
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import os

def f(r):
    res = np.arange(r[0], r[1])
    print(f'I am {os.getpid()}')
    sleep(10)
    print(f'I am {os.getpid()} and I am finished')
    return {'nums': res, 'dubs': res * 2}
```

playground.py:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from fs import f


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    p = ctx.Pool(4)
    with p:
        subsets = [[0, 3], [3, 6], [6, 7]]
        res = [p.apply(f, (subset, )) for subset in subsets]
        print(res)

    print('Done!')
```

Command: `python playground.py`

Output:

```
I am 29881
I am 29881 and I am finished
I am 29882
I am 29882 and I am finished
I am 29881
I am 29881 and I am finished
[{'nums': array([0, 1, 2]), 'dubs': array([0, 2, 4])}, {'nums': array([3, 4, 5]), 
  'dubs': array([ 6,  8, 10])}, {'nums': array([6]), 'dubs': array([12])}]
Done!
```

Comment: you need to use `apply_async`. check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply)

Comment: if you have simple function then process may finish it before other process start.

Comment: maybe you should use `map()` instead of `apply()` - `apply()` may wait for the end of process.

Comment: In the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=apply#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply) it says apply blocks until result is ready. So you're spawning a new subprocess, let it print, then close it, then spawn the next one. If you have an iterable and a function, as suggested below 'Pool.map' is the way to go. If you want more control, 'Pool.apply_async' is the way to go.

Comment: It seems I had implemented map and apply_async wrong. Both seem to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use `p.map()` like this (on Linux Mint)

```
res = p.map(f, subsets)
```

then I get

```
I am 1337328
I am 1337325
I am 1337327
I am 1337328 and I am finished
I am 1337325 and I am finished
I am 1337327 and I am finished
```

Maybe you used `map()` in wrong way. `res = [p.map(f, (subset, )) for subset in subsets]`

---

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    with ctx.Pool(4) as p:
        subsets = [[0, 3], [3, 6], [6, 7]]
        res = p.map(f, subsets)
        print(res)
        
    print('Done!')
```

---

For `apply_async` you would need two `for`-loops

```
    items = [p.apply_async(f, (subset, )) for subset in subsets]
    res = [x.get() for x in items]
    print(res)
```

And both have to be inside `with p:`

---

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    with ctx.Pool(4) as p:
        subsets = [[0, 3], [3, 6], [6, 7]]

        items = [p.apply_async(f, (subset, )) for subset in subsets]
        print(items)
        
        res = [x.get() for x in items]
        print(res)
        
    print('Done!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Each child process is being run one-after-the-other because [`Pool.apply()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply) ***blocks*** until a result is ready — effectively preventing parallel processing from taking place.

Using  [`Pool.map_async()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map_async) instead would prevent that. Note I also made the delay in the `f()` function variable to make the processing times vary.

#### `playground.py`

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
from fs import f


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    pool = ctx.Pool(4)
    with pool:
        subsets = [[0, 3], [3, 6], [6, 7]]
        res = pool.map_async(f, subsets).get(timeout=10)
    pprint(res, sort_dicts=False)

    print('Done!')
```

#### `fs.py`

```
import numpy as np
import os
import random
from time import sleep

def f(r):
    print(f'f({r}) called')
    res = np.arange(r[0], r[1])
    print(f'I am {os.getpid()}')
    sleep(random.uniform(0, 2))  # Random time delay.
    print(f'I am {os.getpid()} and I am finished')
    return {'nums': res, 'dubs': res * 2}
```

Results:

```
f([0, 3]) called
I am 2120
f([3, 6]) called
I am 32208
f([6, 7]) called
I am 13884
I am 2120 and I am finished
I am 13884 and I am finished
I am 32208 and I am finished
[{'nums': array([0, 1, 2]), 'dubs': array([0, 2, 4])},
 {'nums': array([3, 4, 5]), 'dubs': array([ 6,  8, 10])},
 {'nums': array([6]), 'dubs': array([12])}]
```